# How can jQuery function convert into react js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs

I can not idea how can convert jQuery function into react js please help me with this code I try to change into react js

This is jQuery function

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var otherDivs = 
           $(".header").outerHeight() + 
           $(".products_head").outerHeight() + 
           $(".products_active-filters").outerHeight() + 
           $(".pagination").outerHeight() + 
           ($('.my_list-body').innerHeight() - $('.my_list-body').height());
       $('.dynamic_height').height($(window).height() - otherDivs - 10);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful in your case, it make little use of react but most of it can be done using plain vanilla js as well.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const otherDivs =
      document.querySelector(".header").offsetHeight +
      document.querySelector(".products_head").offsetHeight +
      document.querySelector(".products_active-filters").offsetHeight +
      document.querySelector(".pagination").offsetHeight +
      (document.querySelector(".my_list-body").offsetHeight -
        document.querySelector(".my_list-body").clientHeight);
    setHeight(window.innerHeight - otherDivs - 10);
  }, []);

  return <div className="dynamic_height" style={{ height }}></div>;
}
```